# Why does a sequence get called multiple times when there are only one subscriber?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, frp

I have an example [here](http://jsbin.com/lojomuzoku/edit?html,js,console).
There is only one subscriber, but why does a sequence get called 3 times (3 'call' messages)? Imagine that we have API call and...it's a problem. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is not shared and each subscriber triggers the entire chain of transformations. To fix that, call the share operator:

```
          .map(micr => micr.toUpperCase()).share();
```

Comment: Yeah, I know about *share* method. When I have to use it? After each combine method?

Comment: Look at this example: [link](http://jsbin.com/mowozoqowu/edit?html,js,console). Should I call _share_ every time when I combine streams?

Comment: Every time you create a stream with transformation that will be subscribed multiple times